# When did the Gayatri-Mantra appear?

Tags: vedas, history, rig-veda, rishi, gayatri-mantra

The Gayatri-Mantra appeared in the Rigveda, which was composed between c. 1700–1100 BCE.
This Mantra has probably been transmitted from masters to disciples, a long time before being written.

**Question**: When did the Gayatri-Mantra appear orally for the first time (approximately)?

Comment: We can ask the same question for the Mantra "OM".

Comment: I could give you a religious answer, about how and when the gods first gave the Gayatri mantra to humans, but I assume you want some sort of scientific answer.  That would be difficult, because it's hard to assess when a given oral tradition process began.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I'm interested in your religious answer. Is this religious answer also given by oral tradition or does it come from scriptures?

Comment: Well, it comes from Hindu scripture, but all Hindu scripture comes from oral tradition.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Could you please post your religious answer?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by orally? Can you please explain me because I could not understand your question.... :( I think Gayatri Mantra was WRITTEN in Rigveda and was studied in our religion since vedic times, a person who is brahmin when he takes janoi, he is considered iligible for Gayatri Mantra since he take janoi on his body only, others may speak gayatri mantra but can not have protection of janoi. janoi is certificate of a person that he is brahmin. Gayatri Mantra appeared first in Vedas only. orally means?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: The Rigveda is the assembly of texts coming from several rishis (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda#Rishis)), for ex. [Vishvamitra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvamitra) who composed (or received from Gods) the Gayatri-Mantra. I don't think they composed their texts in the same time. In addition, the Rigveda was probably "officially" assembled a long time after the composition of each rishis. If the Gayatri-Mantra is really due to Vishvamitra, then the question is: when did Vishvamitra receive the Gayatri-Mantra (from Gods)?  See  Keshav Srinivasan's comment.

Comment: According to your link, Gayatri Mantra is in Mandala 3 which is composed by Vishwamitra only, so he is the composer of it.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: In my opinion, Wikipedia is not 100% relevant for religious topics. Anyway, this wikipedia page doesn't give a date of composition... which is my question.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux date of composition!! I don't think you will find the exact date. Because vedas are very old. I am also waiting for the answer.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: Yes, a good approximation of the date would also be very interesting.  Keshav Srinivasan seems to have an answer, I don't understand why he doesn't post it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Why you don't post your answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. According to latest research on the dates of Saraswati river and Rama Setu, both these are older than 1700 BCE (NASA's research stated this and I don't currently have links to it.)Therefore ,it is incorrect to date Rig Veda, which existed prior to Rama Avatar, to 1700-1100 BC.
2. The currently-used savitR Gayatri Mantra was revealed to sage Viswamitra who pre-dated Rama. (Age of Rama Setu is >1,750,000 years, see [here](http://krishna.org/nasa-images-discover-ancient-bridge-between-india-and-sri-lanka/)).
3. Prior to savitR (or Sun) gAyatri, people worshipped Indra gAyatri
4. And prior to Indra gAyatri, people worshipped brahma gAyatri.

Points 3 and 4 were researched and revealed by [kAvya kanTha gaNapati muni](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Kavya_Kantha_Vasistha_Ganapati_Muni).

In essence, it is not possible to date the gayatri mantra. We just need to remember that the Supreme pre-dates us and has continually manifested/revealed itself in various forms (mantra, avatAra etc.) since time immemorial. Modern science is too green and immature to help us understand what exists here and beyond. A lot more research by modern scientists (some of whom are rishis themselves - I consider Einstein, Bohr etc. rishis) is needed for us to even get some semblance of an understanding. kEnOpanishad states that brahman is beyond the known and the unknown. So it may very well be that science will never mature to a state where all is explained.

Ref:http://www.vidyavrikshah.org/scripture/upanishads/kena1.html

Comment: Do you have some references about the previous Gayatri you cite: "Brahma Gayatri" before "Indra Gayatri" before "Savitr Gayatri" ?

Comment: kindly provide reference of NASA research ? @moonstar